# MS Word Add-in: RIght click handler

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I am developing an Add-in for MS Word 2010 and I want to add a couple of menu items to the right click menu (only when some text is selected). I have seen a couple of examples to add items but couldn't find how to add items conditionally.
In short I want to override something like OnRightClick handler.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is quite simple, you need to handle the `WindowBeforeRightClick` event. Inside the event locate the required command bar and the specfic control and handle either the `Visible` or the `Enabled` property.

In the example below I toggle the `Visible` property of a custom button created on the Text command bar based on the selection(If selection contains "C#" hide the button otherwise show it)

```
    //using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    //using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

    Word.Application application;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        application = this.Application;
        application.WindowBeforeRightClick +=
            new Word.ApplicationEvents4_WindowBeforeRightClickEventHandler(application_WindowBeforeRightClick);

        application.CustomizationContext = application.ActiveDocument;

        Office.CommandBar commandBar = application.CommandBars["Text"];
        Office.CommandBarButton button = (Office.CommandBarButton)commandBar.Controls.Add(
            Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton);
        button.accName = "My Custom Button";
        button.Caption = "My Custom Button";
    }

    public void application_WindowBeforeRightClick(Word.Selection selection, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (selection != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selection.Text))
        {
            string selectionText = selection.Text;

            if (selectionText.Contains("C#"))
                SetCommandVisibility("My Custom Button", false);
            else
                SetCommandVisibility("My Custom Button", true);
        }
    }

    private void SetCommandVisibility(string name, bool visible)
    {
        application.CustomizationContext = application.ActiveDocument;
        Office.CommandBar commandBar = application.CommandBars["Text"];
        commandBar.Controls[name].Visible = visible;
    }
```

Comment: this was easy, I wonder how I couldn't find this handler after so much googling :) Thanks though

Comment: Setting application to this.Application causes an error, as it's not open yet during ThisAddIn_Startup.