# Customizing Office (Word/Excel/PowerPoint) standard toolbar, ribbon, menu and context menu from my plugin

Tags: excel, plugins, ms-office, hook, office-interop

I've an Office plug-in implemented in C++.

Depends on the context and logic of my plug-in, I would like to enable/disable some existing UI elements of Office (menu, ribbon, context menu, and for old Office CommandBars).

Please help or point me out to resources how to do so (C# or VBA resources also appreciated).

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things to get rid of the main offenders (Ribbon, Command Bar) in Excel VBA.

Show and hide Ribbon interface:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
```

[Show and hide command bars in older versions of Excel](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=282).

Comment: These should also available via the XLCALL32.DLL, see e.g. the XLL SDK.

Answer (score 3):

1) Show hide ribbon items:

You cannot set the enabled state or toggle the visibility of built in ribbon controls, this functionailty is reserved for inner workings of MS Office - [more](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/63e5a99d-ff24-48a9-b56c-a9e962654b58)

The reverse is true, in that you *can* set enabled state or toggle the visibility of your *custom* ribbon items.
And likewise the users will be prevented from changing this via the Customize Ribbon interface:

```
myTabName.Groups[0].Items[0].Enabled = false;
myTabName.Groups[0].Items[1].Visible = false;
```

2) In terms of command bars, Office context menus, you can perform any customizations such as changing enabled and visibility states and adding your own.

You can also change the command bar properties based on a condition - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816358/ms-word-add-in-right-click-handler/13119519#13119519)

3) For a complete list customizations you can and can't do in the ribbon have a look at these two articales:

Office UI Customization - [Comparison of UI Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf08984t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Can I customize the ribbon](http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/word-help/can-i-customize-the-ribbon-HA010227754.aspx)